# Requisições POST para URL específica estão demorando 3 minutos

Tags: php, libcurl

Todas as minhas requisições do tipo POST para uma URL específica estão demorando cerca de **3 minutos** para retornar o **response**, isso é, poucos segundos depois que eu envio o formulário, olho no site da API e lá estão meus dados postados, mas no meu site a requisição fica pendente, depois de exatos 3 minutos ela é finalizada retornando os dados necessários.

Acredito que alguma coisa está **segurando** a resposta por 3 minutos, pois testei o mesmo código em ambiente local e funcionou rapidamente (levou cerca de 10 segundos), o que pode estar causando essa "lentidão"?

```
public function http_request($url, $headers, $data = array())
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    if ($data) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É possível reiniciar o servidor?

Comment: Sim é possível, mas o POST em outras APIs está mais rápido, menos que 10 segundos.

Comment: Sim. Eu entendi que funciona rápido em outra maquina, por isso, sugeri que resetasse o servidor.

Comment: Não em outra máquina, no mesmo servidor, se eu enviar um POST para outra API diferente, é bem rápido. Mesmo assim vou reiniciar ele para "garantir".

Comment: Entendi. Bom, nesse caso a possibilidade de resolver diminuiu bastante. :(

Comment: Infelizmente não resolveu, como pode demorar 3 minutos para retornar uma resposta kk? Eu ainda não acredito nisso

Comment: Você tem certeza de que é o `http_request` que demora 3 minutos? Não há nada antes ou depois? Quando você faz o `curl` para o mesmo site via terminal ele demora os mesmos 3 minutos? O cURL, OpenSSL, GZIP e o PHP estão atualizados, na última versão?

Comment: Sim, estão atualizados. Não consigo testar pelo terminal

Comment: Testei pelo terminal @Inkeliz e me parece que funcionou bem rápido